# How to change data in array, then paste them back changed

Tags: javascript

So i have array    ["test1#1", "test2#1", "test3#1", "test4#1", "test5#0"]
and i want to replace all the #1 and then paste them back inside the same array to same position.

JS:

```
function catData(array) {
  let result = array.map(a => a.TERM + "#" + a.PRIORITY);
  result.forEach(d => {
    if (d.includes("#1")) {
      let less = d.replace("#1", "");
      console.log(less);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function catData(array) {
  let result = array.map(a => a.TERM + "#" + a.PRIORITY);
  result.forEach((d, i) => {
    result[i] = result[i].replace("#1", "") // can replace in place
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use just `map()` like:

```
["test1#1", "test2#1", "test3#1", "test4#1", "test5#0"].map(item => item.replace("#1", "#5"))
```

Note: It will generate a new array, and keep the original.